# Relations between different types of compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

From various articles in Wikipedia, I have seen some relations between several types of compactness.

> In general topological spaces,
>
> [Compact $\Longrightarrow$ Sequentially compact $\Longrightarrow$
>   countably compact $\Longrightarrow$ pseudocompact and weakly countably
>   compact.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Other_forms_of_compactness)

I also saw that

1. > In general topological spaces,
   >
   > Compact $\Longrightarrow$ [σ-compact $\Longrightarrow$ Lindelöf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countability).

   So I was wondering if we can place σ-compact and Lindelöf in the
   first chain of relations? If yes, what are their positions?
2. > In metric spaces,
   >
   > [Compact $\Longleftrightarrow$ Sequentially compact
   >   $\Longleftrightarrow$ countably compact $\Longleftrightarrow$ pseudocompact
   >   $\Longleftrightarrow$ Limit point compact.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Other_forms_of_compactness)

   So I was wondering if we can place Limit point compact in the first
   chain of relations? If yes, what is its position?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: This reminded me of this old MO question I asked: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37195/different-forms-of-compactness-and-their-relation

Comment: @BrunoStonek: Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It’s not true that compactness implies sequential compactness in arbitrary spaces, even if you require them to be Hausdorff: $\beta\omega$ is compact but not sequentially compact. In fact, the sequence $\langle n:n\in\omega\rangle$ has no convergent subsequence.

> **Proof:** Suppose that $\sigma=\langle n_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\langle n:n\in\omega\rangle$ converging to some $p\in\beta\omega$. Clearly $p\in\beta\omega\setminus\omega$, so we can think of $p$ as a free ultrafilter on $\omega$ whose basic open nbhds are the sets $A^*=\{q\in\beta\omega:A\in q\}$ for $A\in p$. Let $A\in p$ be arbitrary, and let $A_0$ and $A_1$ be disjoint infinite subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$. Exactly one of $A_0$ and $A_1$ belongs to $p$, say $A_0$. But then $A_0^*$ is an open nbhd of $p$ that misses every term of $\sigma$ that belongs to $A_1$, so $\sigma$ is not eventually in $A_0^*$ and cannot converge to $p$ after all. $\dashv$

Comment: Thanks, +1! What is $βω$? Does sequential compactness imply compactness?

Comment: @Tim: $\beta\omega$ is the [Čech-Stone compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of the natural numbers. A sequentially compact space need not be compact; $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, with the order topology is a standard counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of counterexamples:
$\mathbb R$ is $\sigma$-compact but not pseudocompact. On the other hand,$\omega_1$ with the order topology is sequentially compact but not $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ isn’t even limit point compact.

Answer (score 1):

> we can place $\sigma$-compact and Lindelöf in the first chain of relations?

No, because it would collapse the chain, since each Tychonoff Lindelöf pseudocompact space $X$ is compact. Indeed, by [Eng, 3.8.11] the space $X$ is paracompact, that is each open cover of the space $X$ has a locally finite open refinement. By [Eng, 3.10.22] the space $X$ is feebly compact, that is if each locally finite family of non-empty open subsets of the space $X$ is finite. We can conclude that the space $X$ is compact.

[image]
[image]

PS. A stratification of different compact-like spaces is much more subtle, see, for instance, basic [Eng, Chap. 3] and general works [DRRT], [Mat], [Vau], [Ste], [Lip]. The relations between different classes of these spaces are well-studied, some of them are presented at the following diagrams: [M, D:3, p.17], [D-AS, D.1, p. 58](for Tychonoff spaces), [Ste, D. 3.6, p. 611], and [GR, p.2].

*References*

[BR] T. Banakh, A. Ravsky. *[Verbal covering properties of topological spaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04480)*,  Topology Appl. ** 201** (2016), 181–205.

[D-AS]A. Dorantes-Aldama, D. Shakhmatov, *Selective  sequential  pseudocompactness*, Topology Appl., **222** (2017), 53–69.

[DRRT] E.K. van Douwen, G.M. Reed, A.W. Roscoe, I.J. Tree, *[Star covering properties](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/bill.roscoe/publications/40.pdf)*, Topology Appl., **39**:1 (1991), 71-103.

[Eng] R. Engelking, *General Topology*, Heldermann Verlag, Berlin, 1989.

[GR] O. Gutik, A. Ravsky, *[On old and new classes of feebly compact spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07454)*, Visnyk of the Lviv Univ. Series Mech. Math. **85** (2018), 48–59.

[Lip] P. Lipparini, *[A very general covering property](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4342)”.

[Mat] M. Matveev, *[A Survey on Star Covering Properties](http://at.yorku.ca/v/a/a/a/19.htm)*.

[Ste] R. M. Stephenson Jr., *Initially $\kappa$-compact and related compact spaces*, in K. Kunen, J. E. Vaughan (eds.), Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology, Elsevier, 1984, P. 603-632.

[Vau] J. E. Vaughan, *Countably compact and sequentially compact spaces*, in K. Kunen, J. E. Vaughan (eds.), Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology, Elsevier, 1984, P. 569-602.